# angularjs Вывод структуры рекурсивной диррективой

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

Доброго времени суток, есть структура данных, соответственно которой нужно реализовать вывод в шаблоне.

```
var cfg = [
    {
        "header": "Заголовок 1",
        "content": [
            {
                "rights": {
                    "_1_list": 0,
                    "_1_get": 0,
                    "_1_delete": 0,
                    "_1_create": 0,
                    "_1_set": 0,
                    "_1_test": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "rights": {
                    "_2_add": 0,
                    "_2_set": 0,
                    "_2_delete": 0,
                    "_2_order": 0,
                    "_2_response.delete": 0,
                    "_2_response.order": 0
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "header": "Заголовок 2",
        "content": [
            {
                "content":[
                    {
                        "header": "Подзаголовок 2.1.1",
                        "rights": {
                            "_3_exists": 0,
                            "_3_get": 0,
                            "_3_set": 0,
                            "_3_delete": 0,
                            "_3_update": 0,
                            "_3_list": 0
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "header": "Подзаголовок 2.1.2",
                        "rights": {
                            "_4_import": 0,
                            "_4_import.probe": 0
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "header": "Подзаголовок 2.1.3",
                        "rights": {
                            "_5_sendconfirm": 0,
                            "_5_confirm": 0,
                            "_5_.get": 0,
                            "_5_.set": 0,
                            "_5_.preview": 0
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "content":[
                    {
                        "header": "Подзаголовок 2.2.1",
                        "rights": {
                            "_6_list": 0,
                            "_6_create": 0,
                            "_6_get": 0,
                            "_6_set": 0,
                            "_6_delete": 0,
                            "_6_clean": 0,
                            "_6_snapshot": 0,
                            "_6_filter.get": 0,
                            "_6_filter.set": 0
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "header": "Подзаголовок 2.2.2",
                        "rights": {
                            "_7_list": 0,
                            "_7_get": 0,
                            "_7_set": 0,
                            "_7_delete": 0
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "header": "Подзаголовок 2.2.3",
                        "rights": {
                            "_8_set": 0,
                            "_8_get": 0,
                            "_8_add": 0,
                            "_8_delete": 0,
                            "_8_erase": 0
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

Само собой посмотрел в сторону рекурсивной диррективы, но к сожалению она виснет на моменте рекурсивного вызова:

```
App.directive('rightsInputGroup',   () => {
    // Runs during compile
    return {
        scope: {
            'items': '=itemslist',
            'change': '&'
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'directives/rights-input-group/template.html',
        replace: true,
        controller: [
            '$scope',
            function($scope) {
                $scope.itemList = angular.copy($scope.items);
            }
        ]
    }

});
```

template.html

```
<div>

    <input-group 
        ng-if="itemList.rights"
        editable="{{myRights['canchange']}}"
        change="change"
        list="itemList.rights"
        header="itemList.header"
    ></input-group>

    <div ng-if="itemList.content" class="grid-row">
        <div ng-repeat="contentItem in itemList.content" class="col-sm-{{ 12/itemList.content.length }} ui-inputs-group">
                <rights-input-group itemslist="contentItem" change="change"></rights-input-group>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

input-group - тоже своя дирректива, но она полностью рабочая, да и до нее еще не доходит ...

Пробовал модифицировать предложеный [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430655/recursion-in-angular-directives) вариант - не работает ...

Comment: что-то я не понял, при чем тут рекурсия? судя по объекту у него не рекурсивная структура - объекты отличаются на двух уровнях, в одном случае content - массив объектов, в другом - массив массивов объектов

Comment: @Grundy, поправил. Надеюсь нагляднее...

Comment: ага, и еще самый первый вызов добавь, это какой-нибудь `<rights-input-group itemslist="cfg" change="change">`?

Comment: @Grundy, не понял =\

Comment: Я имел ввиду на самой странице эта директива как вставлена?

Comment: @Grundy, <rights-input-group ng-repeat="rightsList in cfg" itemslist="rightsList" change="setChanges"></rights-input-group>

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42359/discussion-between-grundy-and-alexey-lemesh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему имеющийся код уже работает. Единственный вариант почему он мог не работать: входные данные отличаются.

```js
angular.module('app', []).
controller('ctrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.cfg = [{
    "header": "Заголовок 1",
    "content": [{
      "rights": {
        "_1_list": 0,
        "_1_get": 0,
        "_1_delete": 0,
        "_1_create": 0,
        "_1_set": 0,
        "_1_test": 0
      }
    }, {
      "rights": {
        "_2_add": 0,
        "_2_set": 0,
        "_2_delete": 0,
        "_2_order": 0,
        "_2_response.delete": 0,
        "_2_response.order": 0
      }
    }]
  }, {
    "header": "Заголовок 2",
    "content": [{
      "content": [{
        "header": "Подзаголовок 2.1.1",
        "rights": {
          "_3_exists": 0,
          "_3_get": 0,
          "_3_set": 0,
          "_3_delete": 0,
          "_3_update": 0,
          "_3_list": 0
        }
      }, {
        "header": "Подзаголовок 2.1.2",
        "rights": {
          "_4_import": 0,
          "_4_import.probe": 0
        }
      }, {
        "header": "Подзаголовок 2.1.3",
        "rights": {
          "_5_sendconfirm": 0,
          "_5_confirm": 0,
          "_5_.get": 0,
          "_5_.set": 0,
          "_5_.preview": 0
        }
      }]
    }, {
      "content": [{
        "header": "Подзаголовок 2.2.1",
        "rights": {
          "_6_list": 0,
          "_6_create": 0,
          "_6_get": 0,
          "_6_set": 0,
          "_6_delete": 0,
          "_6_clean": 0,
          "_6_snapshot": 0,
          "_6_filter.get": 0,
          "_6_filter.set": 0
        }
      }, {
        "header": "Подзаголовок 2.2.2",
        "rights": {
          "_7_list": 0,
          "_7_get": 0,
          "_7_set": 0,
          "_7_delete": 0
        }
      }, {
        "header": "Подзаголовок 2.2.3",
        "rights": {
          "_8_set": 0,
          "_8_get": 0,
          "_8_add": 0,
          "_8_delete": 0,
          "_8_erase": 0
        }
      }]
    }]
  }];
}).directive('rightsInputGroup', () => {
  // Runs during compile
  return {
    scope: {
      'item': '=',
      'change': '&'
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'directives/rights-input-group/template.html',
    replace: true,
    controller: [
      '$scope',
      function($scope) { 
        $scope.itemList = angular.copy($scope.items);
      }
    ]
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller="ctrl as vm">
  <rights-input-group data-ng-repeat="item in vm.cfg" item="item"></rights-input-group>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="directives/rights-input-group/template.html">
    <div>
      <h3>{{item.header}}</h3>
      <div ng-if="item.rights">Content Rights:</div>
      <div ng-repeat="(r,v) in item.rights">{{r}} - {{v}}</div>
      <div data-ng-repeat="c in item.content">
        <rights-input-group item="c"></rights-input-group>
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>
</div>
```

#### Небольшая памятка: как делать рекурсивные шаблоны

1. Обращать внимание на входные данные: в них не должно быть циклических ссылок
2. В шаблоне вызывать себя же **только** в том случае, когда данные действительно есть.
3. Стараться использовать переменные из текущего скопа.
4. Если в шаблоне подключается он же с помощью `ng-include` - стараться заключать его в элемент создающий свой собственный скоп.
5. Если рекурсивно используется директива, лучше использовать изолированные скоп, чтобы не было конфликтов с родительскими переменными.